# OpenLayers not refreshing a layer

Tags: openlayers-2, wms, wfs, refresh

I have a problem with refreshing layers.  I have WMS and WFS layers from one source. I edit WFS and after do `wms_layer.redraw(true)` but the layer redraws only after zoom in or zoom out.

Same with WFS. I have `wfs_layer.visibility=false` and do `wfs_layer.visibility=true` `wfs_layer.refresh({force:true})`. And layer refreshes only after zoom in or zoom out.

For doing these operations do I have to do something special?

Comment: I'm not sure but for manipulating of visibility of layers you should use setVisibility method of layer not set up visibility property directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For redraw WMS layer use [redraw](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/HTTPRequest-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.HTTPRequest.redraw) method of OpenLayers.Layer.HTTPRequest. For example:

```
wms_layer.redraw(true);
```

[Refresh](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/apidocs/files/deprecated-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.WFS.refresh) method doesn't pass any parameters, so for redraw wfs layer use the following syntax:

```
wfs_layer.refresh();
```

Comment: to force the redraw of a wms layer I needed to do    wms_layer.redraw('now')  where the parameter will be evalueted as TRUE, In the above example true may or may not have a value and if it does not the layer will not redraw

Answer (score 2):

In OL 3.10.1 I do:

```
WMSLayer.getSource().updateParams({"time": Date.now()});
WFSLayer.clear();
```

Both layers (WMS and WFS) are refreshed succesfully.