# Reload the dimension values of a layer with OpenLayers 4

Tags: openlayers, wms, layers

I'm looking to reload the dimension values of a layer with OpenLayers 4.

My problem is when my App calls the GetCapabilities of the layer, the dimensions received are for a certain datetime, for example:

```
<Dimension name="time" units="ISO8601" default="2018-07-27T14:20:00Z" nearestValue="0">2018-07-27T11:20:00Z/2018-07-27T14:20:00Z/PT10M</Dimension>
```

but after a couple of hours, those datetime values are expired, so when I call the GetMap with these date parameters, the WMS tell me:

```
Invalid model run or date or timestamp value out of time domain : 2018-07-27T11:30:00Z/2018-07-27T14:30:00Z/PT10M
```

I try:

```
layer.getSources().refresh()
```

but it doesn't work. Is it something possible to do without delete/add the layer?

Comment: I try this too https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30680/openlayers-not-refresh-a-layer#30683 but it's for layer image not layer definition

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue, if you are saying that you do a GetMap request with a specific time parameter which you know expires; won't refresh just make the same request and fail (that seems correct).  You'll need to regenerate the request with the new time values.

Comment: I need to call the getCapabilities again to get the "refreshed" time parameters from the WMS. With this "fresh" parameters, I will be able to call the getMap with correct parameters. If you want to take a look at the WMS: http://geo.weather.gc.ca/geomet?request=GetCapabilities&service=wms&version=1.3.0&LAYERS=RADAR_1KM_RDBR